# Why Is My AABB Collision Detection Not Working

Tags: java, collision-detection, 3d, lwjgl, aabb

I am going to be making a 3D game and I need to be able to test for accurate collision. I was able to get bounding sphere collision working (too inaccurate to be used for the whole game), but AABB collision is much harder (and more accurate!). I used the code from [this website](http://www.miguelcasillas.com/?p=30) and I can't seem to get it to work. I have my code below for the AABB collision method:

```
public boolean isColliding (AABB other) {
Vector3f otherMax = new Vector3f(other.pos.x + other.w, other.pos.y + other.h, other.pos.z + other.d);
Vector3f otherMin = new Vector3f(other.pos.x, other.pos.y, other.pos.z);

Vector3f thisMin = new Vector3f(this.pos.x + this.w, this.pos.y + this.h, this.pos.z + this.d);
Vector3f thisMax = new Vector3f(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z);

return (otherMax.x > thisMin.x && otherMin.x < thisMax.x
        && otherMax.y > thisMin.y && otherMin.y < thisMax.y
        && otherMax.z > thisMin.z && otherMin.z < thisMax.z);
}
```

I'm not quite sure where this is going wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `thisMin` and `thisMax` declarations reversed.

```
Vector3f thisMin = new Vector3f(this.pos.x + this.w, this.pos.y + this.h, this.pos.z + this.d);
Vector3f thisMax = new Vector3f(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z);
```

should be:

```
Vector3f thisMin = new Vector3f(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z);
Vector3f thisMax = new Vector3f(this.pos.x + this.w, this.pos.y + this.h, this.pos.z + this.d);
```

Comment: Another key takeaway is that you'll go much further (and faster) when you can suspect and debug basic things like this...